# Confusion with tensorflow's Sequential Dense

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm working on a regression probem using Tensorflow, and have created two models with slight differences in their first Dense layer.

## The Models

```
# Create some regression data
X_regression = tf.range(0, 1000, 5)
y_regression = tf.range(100, 1100, 5) # Y = X+ 100

# Split regression data into training and test sets
X_reg_train = X_regression[:150]
X_reg_test = X_regression[150:]
y_reg_train = y_regression[:150]
y_reg_test = y_regression[150:]
```

**Model 1**

```
# Setup random seed
tf.random.set_seed(42)


model_1_reg = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(100),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])


model_1_reg.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.mae,
                    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                    metrics=['mae'])

model_1_reg.fit(tf.expand_dims(X_reg_train, axis=-1), y_reg_train, epochs=100)
```

**Model 2**

```
# Setup random seed
tf.random.set_seed(42)


model_2_reg = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, input_shape=(None, 1)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])


model_2_reg.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.mae,
                    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                    metrics=['mae'])

model_2_reg.fit(tf.expand_dims(X_reg_train, axis=-1), y_reg_train, epochs=100)
```

I'm confused about whether I should add the `input_shape` or not. **Model 1**'s input shape becomes `(None, 1)` and **Model 2**'s input becomes `(None, None, 1)`.

Both of them run, but perform differently.

**Model 2** makes sense since we're inputting an array, but if I think about it, does that mean I only have a single node in the input layer? Since I'm giving it a whole ndarray instead of the instances it self. **Model 1** makes sense too since I want to give each number into it.

So, which one makes sense more? Or what case should I use each model for?
Also, for **model 2**'s fit why does doing

```
tf.expand_dims(X_reg_train, axis=-1)
```

for the X of

```
model_2_reg.fit(tf.expand_dims(X_reg_train, axis=-1), y_reg_train, epochs=100
```

work? I thought we're suppose to put it in as a batch or like an array of the data so it should be inside an `ndarray`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you give the input shape with the `input_shape` parameter, you exclude the batch dimension. That's why you get `(None, None, 1)` for `Model 2`, because TF inserts the first `None` batch dimension in addition to the shape you provide. I'm actually a bit surprised that `Model 2` runs with the additional `None` dimension. If you provide no `input_shape`, TensorFlow will try to pick it from the `x` parameter of `model.fit` (so your `tf.expand_dims(X_reg_train, axis=-1)`).

As for your second question

> why does `tf.expand_dims(X_reg_train, axis=-1)` work?

It is actually required. For a dense network, the input shape is expected to be `(samples, features)`, even with only one feature. The `tf.expand_dims` provides that shape, because you go from shape `(200,)` to `(200, 1)`. You could do the same with `np.expand_dims`, as TF accepts numpy arrays as input. Under the hood TF would convert it to `Tensors` though, so it makes no (real) difference if you provide numpy arrays or TensorFlow tensors.

Comment: I think the second model works when I add None because when I fit it, I think it thinks that the ndarray is an instance, so in a sense I'm only fitting 1 instance (?). I think this is the case because when I actually set the input_shape as `(1,)` and give it the nd array, it performs way better. What do you think?

Comment: I'm actually not sure how TF handles the `(None, None, 1)` shape. It's interesting that the model performs worse with that. I thought that TF would recognize the `None` axis as flatten-able and does that, as the `Dense` layer needs 1D input data to connect to, but it seems that it gets handled differently.